# Counterintuitive suggestion in the "missing argument list"-error message for methods with multiple argument lists?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

Consider the following code snippet:

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
foo
```

It does not compile, and produces the following error message:

```
error: missing argument list for method foo
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when 
  a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing 
`foo _` or `foo(_)(_)` instead of `foo`.
```

The `foo _` hint works. But if I write the expression

```
foo(_)(_)
```

as suggested by the previous error message, I get a new error message:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded 
function ((x$1: <error>, x$2: <error>) => foo(x$1)(x$2))
```

This seems rather counterintuitive.

Under what circumstances is the `foo(_)(_)`-hint supposed to be helpful, *what exactly does it tell me*?

*(noise removed; the more I kept editing the question, the less sense did it make; Kolmar is right)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `foo(_)(_)` is `(Int, Int) => Int`. So it works if you specify that type or use it in the context that expects this type:

```
scala> foo(_: Int)(_: Int)
res1: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1120/1321433666@798b36fd

scala> val f: (Int, Int) => Int = foo(_)(_)
f: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1121/1281445260@2ae4c424

scala> def bar(f: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = f(10, 20)
bar: (f: (Int, Int) => Int)Int

scala> bar(foo(_)(_))
res2: Int = 30
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I guess I just really managed to look at the error messages though the eyes of an unsuspecting novice while I was trying to understand [what exactly could be unclear about this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410976/what-does-an-underscore-after-a-scala-method-call-mean?noredirect=1).